# MongoDB: How to find documents with date formatted as string 2021-04-04 12:40:05

Tags: mongodb, date, find

I'm trying to find documents in MongoDB in a field defined as date but some documents contain date string like this `2021-04-04 12:40:05` and can't find them using the query. Other documents contain correct format and I can select them like this

```
const today = new Date();
pastDate = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 10);
console.log(pastDate);
const transactions = await transactionMongoModel.find({ creationTime: { $lt: pastDate } })
  .select({ _id: 1, creationTime: 1 })
  .sort({ creationTime: -1 })
  .limit(100);
```

but this query doesn't return documents with creating time formatted this way `2021-04-04 12:40:05` how can I find them?

Comment: Date/time should be **never** stored as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Use [$dateFromString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) to convert the string into a `Date` object.

Comment: You can compare data of the same types. If you know if some of your data is in different formats, then use aggregation date/string operators to convert while comparing.

Comment: I don't save it this way it was just a mistake with many records and trying to find them now in one query

Answer (score 1):

At first Date should not be stored as string, its better to bulk update your date fields in mongo first.

But if its end of time you could use [dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator to first convert to date format and then compare.

```
transactionMongoModel.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": {
      "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": "$creationTime"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$match": { "date": { "$lt": pastDate.toDate() }}},
  {"$project": {"date":0, "_id": 1, "creationTime" : 1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I got this error ````TypeError: pastDate.toDate is not a function````

Comment: Whats the value of pastDate ?. If its not valid, toDate will most probably throw error

Comment: pastDate: 1618149772740

Comment: Thats a timestamp! converting your timestamp to date is needed `new Date(pastDate)`

Comment: ````{ $match: { date: { $lt: new Date(pastDate) } } },```` and got 
````MongoError: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot do inclusion on field creationTime in exclusion projection````

Comment: Remove date:0 from project field

Comment: nothing in the console at all it didn't log anything ````console.log('transactions', transactions);````